# Google Maps Categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem that I have not managed to solve.

I developed a small script to load a Google Map. This script uses HTML 5 to determine your current location and then shows you some places on the map. These are places that are read from a MySQL database.

The issue is that somehow I need to filter them by category. A PHP file is responsible for generating an XML file from the MySQL database.

I could pass the following parameter to select the category: file.php?category=something

```
downloadUrl("file.php?cat=something", function(data) {
        var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("name"), markers[i].getAttribute("address"), markers[i].getAttribute("type"), latlng);
        }
        });
```

The issue is that I want to go changing category when I click on a link for example.

Imagine you have a map to the left and right categories. Then when clicking on a category, the map automatically remove the places marked on the current category and only shows the new category.

In conclusion, the part where it says file.php? Category = something, the value "something" should be changed dynamically.

I think it could do with Jquery but I do not know exactly how. I tried several ways and still not do it.

I just need a way to change the value of this part and that the map will automatically disable the other categories, for example:

```
var something = doctor;
downloadUrl("file.php?cat="+something, function(data) {
```

This is the complete code of my script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocalización</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="util.js"></script>

  </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="info"></div>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 780px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var infowindow;
        var geocoder;
        var marker;

        function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 14,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

        downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php?cat=doctor", function(data) {
        var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("name"), markers[i].getAttribute("address"), markers[i].getAttribute("type"), latlng);
        }
        });

        function createMarker(name, address, type, latlng) {

        if(type=="doctor"){
        var image = 'clinicas-y-hospitales.png';
        }else{
        var image = 'carabineros-y-seguridad.png';
        }

        var contentString = '<h2>'+name+'</h2> <br /><p>'+address+'</p>';   

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map, icon: image});
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString, maxWidth: 200});
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        return marker;
        }

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        // Try HTML5 geolocation
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(pos);

        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': pos}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: pos,
              map: map
          });

          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: '<p><strong>Usted está aquí:</strong> '+results[1].formatted_address+'</p>'});
          infowindow.open(map, marker);

          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = results[1].formatted_address;
        }
        } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
        });

          }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
          });

        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }
      }

        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
        if (errorFlag) {
          var content = 'Error: La geolocalización ha fallado.';
        } else {
          var content = 'Error: Tu navegador no soporta geolocalización.';
        }

        var options = {
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
          content: content
        };

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
        map.setCenter(options.position);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

To see the script running are here:

http://pruebas.davidbanner.cl/geo/index.php

A similar example of what I need to do is here:

http://mapas.vinadelmarchile.cl/index.php

Thank you very much to anyone who can give me an idea or help with code.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to let's say put a button or link and on the [click event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) implement the call to get the xml.

If you need further assistance please make a working example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/argiropoulostauros/cQLRr/)) and post it here in the comments so we can take a look.